# Extending collection methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Source of issue: I have `Stream` model, which `has_may :students` `:through => :assignments`. `Student` has an associated account. I needed to have default order: `@stream.students` to be ordered by `students.account.surname DESC`

After some time I decided that something like with is not set up by Rails predefined methods, so I decided to redefine `Stream` instance method `students`.

```
  def students(options={})
    opt = options || {:order=>true, :attr=>"surname", :way=>"DESC"}
    if opt[:order]
      students = Student.joins("INNER JOIN assignments ON students.id = assignments.student_id WHERE assignments.stream_id = #{self.id}").includes(:account).order("accounts.#{opt[:attr]} #{opt[:way]}")
    else
      students = Student.joins("INNER JOIN assignments ON students.id = assignments.student_id WHERE assignments.stream_id = #{self.id}").includes(:account)
    end
  end
```

And it worked quite fine until I discovered, that some of collection methods stoped to work, like `stream.students.delete(@student)`.

So I need not to override, but extend functionality of `@stream.students` method.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to handle this with rails methods:

```
has_many :students, -> { joins(:account).order('accounts.surname') }, through: :assignments
```

Comment: wouldn't ` includes ` be more preferable it I need to retrieve account data nearly every time loading collection?

Comment: `includes` does not add join statement and you cannot order on column which is not returned by the query. You can add `includes` above as well, however my experience is taht default preloading association ends up badly. `includes` is actually quite dangerous, especially when used together with a join on same association, I have recently gave a talk on that subject: https://skillsmatter.com/skillscasts/6731-activerecord-vs-n-1